# Prevent double submission of form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

**Problem:**

I have a script where the user can press the keys C or M to choose an option. Once either key is pressed the form will be submitted. Since there is a strict rule that each option can be submitted once, some press multiple times.

**Question:**

How can I prevent users from submitting the form again after they have pressed the C or M key? I want them to be able to press either key once the page refresh after submission.

**Code in PHP / jQuery:**

```
if (in_array($checkstring, $footer))
    {
        echo '
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    $(window).keypress(function(e)
                    {
                        if (e.which == 99)
                        {
                            $("input#left").val( 1 );
                            $("form").submit();
                        }
                        else if (e.which == 109)
                        {
                            $("input#right").val( 1 );
                            $("form").submit();
                        }
                    });

                    '.$warning.'
                });
            </script>
        ';
    }
```

Comment: are you sure 99 and 109 are c and m?

Comment: @Class http://expandinghead.net/keycode.html

Comment: because 99 = minus and 109 = 3 on the keypad for me

Comment: That's quite interesting, tried it on Windows desktop keyboard and MacBook Air keyboard and it's the same. Both cases it's a Swedish keyboard, maybe you have a diff. setup?

Comment: Luckily none of my participants use that :-)

Comment: this looks like what I'm seeing http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: I will try 67 and 77 to see if there's any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking you are looking for something like:

which creates a Boolean variable set to false and if the variable is false and key = C|M set once to true then the function won't run submit again because once is true and not false

```
var once = false;
$(window).keypress(function(e){
    if(!once){
        if(e.which == 99){
            $("input#left").val( 1 );
            $("form").submit();
            once = true;
            //maybe a function to time out to reset once after x seconds?
        }else if (e.which == 109){
            $("input#right").val( 1 );
            $("form").submit();
            once = true;
            //maybe a function to time out to reset once after x seconds?
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks promising, I will try this and get back with feedback.

Comment: I don't think there's a need for a time out function since the code is loaded using require_once() function in PHP and will automatically set once to false when the page refresh.

Comment: @kexxcream i didn't know if you wanted a function to timeout to allow another execution so i put that in there as a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
var once = false;
$(window).keypress(function(e){
    if(!once){
        if(e.which == 99 || e.which == 109){
            $("input#"+(e.which == 99)?"left":"right").val( 1 );
            $("form").submit();
            once = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
     $(window).keypress(function(e)
    e.stopPropagation();
 /* here we apply this because when we press

 click then it takes form submit action

 so we prevent all the things when we

 press key as you mention in your code*/
                        {
                            if (e.which == 99)
                            {
                                $("input#left").val( 1 );
                                $("form").submit();
                            }
                            else if (e.which == 109)
                            {
                                $("input#right").val( 1 );
                                $("form").submit();
                            }
                        });

reference [event.stopPropagation()][1]


  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/
```